# Is it possible to have a timeout in a persisted key in Redis?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to have an in-memory key with an expiration of e.g. 12hrs, which at the expiration time is stored as a persistent key with an expiration of 48hrs?

Comment: NO, you CANNOT do that with Redis.

Comment: You need an external controller app for that.